# If R is a PID and I is an ideal of R, then every ideal of the quotient ring R/I is a principal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Solution,ideas and hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Hint: What is the relationship between ideals in the quotient ring $R/I$ and ideals in $R$?

Answer (score 7):

Do you know the Fourth (or Lattice) Isomorphism Theorem?

> **Theorem**: Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal. Then the map
>   $J\mapsto J/I$ is a bijection between the set of ideals of $R$ containing $I$ and the set of ideals of $R/I$.

In particular, this means that every ideal of $R/I$ is the quotient of some (in your case, principal) ideal of $R$. Can you see how that helps?

Answer (score 2):

So in other words, you need to show that if $R$ is a PID, then so is the quotient ring $R/I$.

Here's a hint: consider the standard map $\phi:R\to R/I$.  What does $\phi$ do to an ideal in $R$?  What can we say about the generators of ideals in $R/I$?